# Reproducir Sonidos en C o C++ Sin Usar Libreria Allegro

Tags: c++, c

¿Como colocar a reproducir sonidos en formato *midi*, *wav*, sin el uso de la librería *Allegro* en los lenguajes *C* o *C++*?

Comment: No te gusta Allegro, pero no dices por qué... pues bueno, usa otra librería de audio como [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) que es usable tanto en C como en C++.

Answer (score 1):

Ni C ni C++ tienen librerías estándares para reproducir sonidos, así que siempre vas a necesitar una librería externa (a no ser que seas tan valiente como para interactuar con los drivers de la tarjeta de sonido, tu solo, y a mano).

Si no quieres usar Allegro, puedes utilizar [SDL Mixer](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/).

Comment: Cómo se configura

Comment: @TwistCode No puedo ayudarte en eso, lo siento, así que google. Aparte de que no trabajo con Windows, hace como 8 años que no utilizo SDL.